# Mostrar imagen guardadas en mysql en PHP con URL amigables y POO

Tags: mysql, mvc, poo, imagen, upload

No estoy pudiendo mostrar una imagen que esta en mysql en un campo blob. Funciona el guardar las imágenes al mysql, puedo recuperar los datos, pero cuando quiero mostrarlo no puedo.
Trate de implementar el ejemplo que se da en esta web: [baulphp](https://www.baulphp.com/cargar-y-almacenar-imagen-en-mysql-php/)

Básicamente lo que hace es llamar a un archivo PHP que recupere la imagen y la devuelva reescribiendo la cabecera con la función header y luego un echo del contenido. Pero el tema es que yo estoy intentando esto en un proyecto MVC y POO, y la url estan amigables y se reescriben a través de .htaccess. Entonces, no puedo llamar directamente a un archivo PHP como el ejemplo de esa web...

Esta chequeado que el objeto de la base de datos llega, y trae bien los datos.

Probé hacer eso del ejemplo en una acción de controlador, y llamarlo dentro de la etiqueta IMG pero tampoco me funciono.

esto es mi codigo, estes el formulario de la vista:

```
    <form method="POST" action="<?= BASE_URL ?>productos/<?= $metodo ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2><?= $texbut ?> Producto</h2>
        <p><label for="p_nombre">Nombre del Producto:<span class="asterisco">&nbsp;*</span></label></p>
        <p><input type="text" name="p_nombre" <?= $_SESSION['abm_prod'] == 3 ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '' ?> 
                  value="<?= $_SESSION['abm_prod'] > 1 ? $prod2edit->p_nombre : ''; ?>" id="p_nombre" maxlength="100" 
                  required="required" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Ingrese nombre del producto..."> </p>
        
        <p><label for="p_descrip">Descripcion del Producto:</label></p>
        <p><textarea name="p_descrip" <?= $_SESSION['abm_prod'] == 3 ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '' ?> 
                  id="p_descripcion" autofocus="autofocus" 
                  placeholder="Ingrese descripción del producto..."><?= $_SESSION['abm_prod'] > 1 ? $prod2edit->p_descripcion : ''; ?></textarea></p>
        
        <p><label for="p_red">Nombre reducido:</label></p>
        <p><input type="text" name="p_red" <?= $_SESSION['abm_prod'] == 3 ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '' ?> 
                  value="<?= $_SESSION['abm_prod'] > 1 ? $prod2edit->p_red : ''; ?>"
                  id="p_red" maxlength="20" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Ingrese nombre reducido/corto..."> </p>
        
        <p><label for="p_imagen">Cargar foto del producto</label></p>
        <div class="abmformcontent2 clearfix">
            <div class="abmformleft">
                <input class="botonfoto" type="file" name="p_imagen" />
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['errorimg'])): ?>
                        <p class="errores"><?= $_SESSION['errorimg'] ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <p><label for="p_precio">Precio:<span class="asterisco">&nbsp;*</span></label></p>
                <p><input class="inputval" type="text" name="p_precio" <?= $_SESSION['abm_prod'] == 3 ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '' ?> 
                          value="<?= $_SESSION['abm_prod'] > 1 ? $prod2edit->p_precio : ''; ?>"
                          id="p_precio" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Ingrese precio del producto ..."> </p>

                <p><label for="p_stock">Stock:</label></p>
                <p><input class="inputval" type="number" name="p_stock" <?= $_SESSION['abm_prod'] == 3 ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '' ?> 
                          value="<?= $_SESSION['abm_prod'] > 1 ? $prod2edit->p_stock : ''; ?>"
                          id="p_stock" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Stock actual..."> </p>

                <?php $categorias = Utilidades::Cat_for_menu(); ?>
                <p><label for="p_catid">Seleccione Categoría:</label></p>
                <select class="selectorcat" name="p_catid" <?= $_SESSION['abm_prod'] == 3 ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '' ?>>
                    <?php while ($cat = $categorias->fetch_object()): ?>
                    <option value="<?= $cat->c_id ?>" <?= $_SESSION['abm_prod'] > 1 && $cat->c_id==$prod2edit->p_categoria_id ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >
                        <?= $cat->c_nombre ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="abmformright">
                <img src='<?= BASE_URL ?>productos/viewimg&p_id=<?= $prod2edit->p_id ?>' alt='Imagen producto'   />
            </div>
        </div>

        <p><input type="number" hidden="hidden" name="p_id" value="<?= isset($prod2edit->p_id) ? $prod2edit->p_id : ''; ?>" ></p>
        
        <div class="boton3">
            <input type="submit" class="boton" value="Confirmar">
            <a href="<?=BASE_URL?>productos/gestion"><input type="button" class="boton" value="Cancelar"></a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Y aca esta parte del controlador y la accion:

```
require_once 'models/mproductos.php';
require_once 'models/mimages.php';

Class ProductosController{
    
    public function viewimg() {
        
        $id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'p_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

        if($id>0){
            //Credenciales de conexion
            $Host = 'localhost';
            $Username = 'prueba';
            $Password = '123456';
            $dbName = 'macrotienda';

            //Crear conexion mysql
            $db = new mysqli($Host, $Username, $Password, $dbName);

            //revisar conexion
            if($db->connect_error){
               die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
            }

            //Extraer imagen de la BD mediante GET
            $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE i_producto = $id");

            if($result->num_rows > 0){
                $imgDatos = $result->fetch_assoc();
                
                //Mostrar Imagen
                header("Content-type: ".$imgDatos['i_mimetype']); 
                echo $imgDatos['i_content']; 
            }else{
                echo 'Imagen no existe...';
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    // *************************************************************************
    
    public function gestion() {

        $productos = new mProductos();
        $allproductos = $productos->Traer_Todos();
        require_once 'views/products/gestion.php';
        
    }
```

Aca esta cuando grabo la imagen en la base de datos:

```
public function create() {
    $insert = "insert into macrotienda.images values(null,".
              " '$this->filename', ".
              " '$this->mimetype', ".
              "  $this->height,    ".
              "  $this->width,     ".
              " '$this->hwtext',   ".
              "  $this->size,      ".
              " '$this->content',  ".
              "  now(),            ".
              "  $this->producto_id ) ";

    $result = $this->conn->query($insert);
    return $result;
```

aca esta cuando asigno a ese objeto los datos de la imagen:

```
        $imagen  = $_FILES['p_imagen'];

        $ftype = $imagen['type'];
        $fsize = $imagen['size'];

        $ftmp   = $imagen['tmp_name'];
        
        $ftamaño = getimagesize($ftmp);

        $image = new mimages();
        $image->setFilename($imagen['name']);
        $image->setHeight($ftamaño[0]);
        $image->setWidth($ftamaño[1]);
        $image->setHwtext($ftamaño[3]);
        $image->setMimetype($ftype);
        $image->setSize($fsize);
        $image->setContent(addslashes(file_get_contents($ftmp)));
```

Aclaración: Como se ve ahi en la accion "viewimg" esta todo lo de la conexion, eso solo esta en modo de prueba, pues, en realidad esa clase hereda los parametros de conexión, probe de ambas formas y ambas reciben el objeto de la base de datos...

Soy nobato todavía en la programación en PHP ... como podria mostrar la imagen ?

MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: Hola Pedro. El que te hayas basado en una web de los millones que hay importa poco. Ahora lo que importa es lo que estás haciendo tú, qué código, qué errores, qué pruebas o depuraciones has hecho, etc. Tienes que agregar eso a la pregunta para que podamos revisarlo y ayudarte.

Comment: ahi agregue parte de mi codigo... gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué comportamiento tiene ese código, muestra algo, no muestra nada, que muestra?

Comment: No muestra la imagen, es como si no encontrara la imagen, por lo que pude probar, ni siquiera va a la accion viewimg ...

Comment: Ok, no muestra la imagen, pero ¿qué muestra? ¿la página se queda en blanco, muestra algún error, muestra algún mensaje en pantalla? El código es extenso y si no pones en qué punto falla es complicado meterse a analizar un programa completo. Mientras más específico seas planteando la pregunta más rápido podremos ubicarnos los demás en el contexto.

Comment: Ya lo solucione... Pregunte en stackoverflow en ingles y me pasaron un post que al ver encontre la solucion... tenia este ejemplo:

echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( stripslashes($result['image']) ).'"/>';

eso asi no me funciono, me mostraba todo mal, como una imagen dañada, pero cuando puse la etiqueta  img asi:

<?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($_SESSION['img_prod']->i_content ).'"  />'; ?>

me funciono... lamentablemente no entiendo bien como funciona esa función base64_encode, tuve que sacar stripslashes para que funcione. Grax!

Answer (score 0):

Aca esta la solución:

En el formulario de la vista debe ir así:

```
<div class="abmformright">
     <?php if(isset($_SESSION['img_prod'])): ?>
          <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($_SESSION['img_prod']->i_content ).'" />'; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Muchas Gracias!